# Can't load csv files which are in zipped in Mac

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, macos, file

I am using mac m2. I have a folder on my PC and inside this folder, there are 10 CSV files that are in gz format. But whenever I am trying to read them it is showing FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

```
folder_path="/Users/name/Desktop/newdata/newdata-1.2/data/"
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, "*.csv.gz"))

# Read the CSV files into separate dataframes
dfs = []
for file in file_list:
    with gzip.open(file, 'rt') as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
        dfs.append(df)
```

Comment: Did you try `os.path.exists('/Users/name/Desktop/newdata/newdata-1.2/data/onecsvfile.csv.gz')`? (Replace `onecsvfile` by a real file name)

Answer (score 0):

when you use gzip.open(), f will be a gzip object like so:

```
<gzip _io.BufferedReader name='sample.csv.gz' 0x111eb6fd0>
```

which you cannot pass to pd.read_csv()-- but, the method supports gzip files :)

```
import pandas as pd
import os
dfs = []
files = Path('.').glob('*.csv.gz')
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, compression='gzip')
    dfs.append(df)
print(dfs)
```

I ran this with a sample .csv.gz and it appended the df to the list:

```
[   id    name
0   1  TEST_1
1   2  TEST_2
2   3  TEST_3
3   4  TEST_4]
```

hope this helps!